# How can I understand the performance tradeoffs in Cocoa library classes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, computer-science

Today I was asked how long an NSMutableDictionary insertion takes, were that dictionary to contain 1,000,000 elements. Not coming from a computer science background, I had absolutely no idea. I was surprised to learn that it completes in (what I now understand to be called) O(n) time. Great. Wonderful.

**How could someone know that, definitively?**

Obviously, one could just write dozens and dozens of tests against every single Cocoa class and chart out all the time data. I'll be sure to get around to that when I have a few weeks of free time. Barring all of that...

- Is this just super obvious to someone with a computer science
  background?
- Does Apple publish documentation that explains
  this?
- Does his knowledge imply that he, being a computer
  science expert, did his own testing to discover this?

Comment: A good article on Foundation collection classes and their performance: http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html

Comment: Thank you for that link. Now that I'm coming to grips with the terminology, it should be easier to discover such articles on my own in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about is called the ["complexity" of an algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). It is language independent; `NSDictionary` time complexity is no different than any other associative dictionary such as C++ `std::map`. However, that doesn't mean that an `NSDictionary` filled with some objects is guaranteed to be able to perform `insert`, `search`, or `delete` operations as quickly as an `std::map`; all it means is that the time it takes to do those operations is *linear* (O(n)), *on worst case*, in relation to the number of elements (the *n* part of O(n)). Dictionary insertion *could be* O(1), which is constant time (operation takes the same amount of time independent of the number of elements in the dictionary) *if* there were no hash collisions.

The "algorithm" employed by an `NSDictionary` is called a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). A hash table does insertion by hashing the *key* input (a constant time operation), then resolving collisions, an O(n) operation. Hopefully you can see that, in the worst case, *all* of your `insert` operations will collide, which is O(n).

Tables/hashing algorithms can of course be specialized to reduce collisions within a specific set of data, but `NSDictionary` just uses the objects `hash` method of your *key* objects, which you can override for your `NSObject` subclasses if you need some sort of specialization (probably not).

Since it is a general purpose dictionary and not specialized for a specific set of data, we don't necessarily need to know the implementation details of `NSDictionary` (Apple's [documentation for `NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesnt mention specifics)  to know that these operations will be O(n). Neither do we have to run "tests" to discover the complexity.

Comment: With your description, you've put me on the track to understanding this more deeply. More importantly, you've put me on track to understanding how to research it on my own from here on out. Thank you.

Comment: @christopherdrum thanks, I just updated with a bit more info on `NSDictionary`